# Spread events in time, based on participants, for maximum time in between

Tags: algorithm, time, scheduling

Ok, this is a real life problem and I'm trying to find an algorithm (if it exists) or even the scientific name for the problem. The problem goes as follows:

We have `N` time slots, and we know `N` tuples in the form `(start, end)` marking the start and end timestamps of each time slot.

We also have `N` events which we want to match to the `N` time slots. Each event goes to only one time slot and one time slot has only one event. All events must be matched to a time slot. Each event has `P` participants.

What the algorithm should do, is match the events to the time slots, so that the cumulative time between two events is maximized. The cumulative time is the total time waited by all participants combined (so that the mean participant has the maximum time between two events, if that makes sense).

The real life application is for the order of subjects in a university at the end of a semester, so that the subjects can be as spread out as they can, based on the number of students that have to study for each subject, so that the mean student has the maximum possible time to study between each subject.

For further clarifications, please leave a comment.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that events with a lot of overlap in attendance should be spaced far apart and events with little overlap can be placed closer to each other?

Comment: Calculate the overlap for each subject pair. With overlap I understand the number of students that takes both subjects. The overlap determines the cost of placing two courses close to each other. Start with the highest overlap pair then work your way down, placing  each new subject with sufficient distance from others with high overlap. Note that there are diminishing returns. A space of `t` days between subjects (`t` depends on the size of the subject) should be sufficient, adding more will have little benefit.